# Error in hello world spray app with scala 2.11

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I'm trying to get a simple "hello world" server running using spray with scala 2.11:

```
import spray.routing.SimpleRoutingApp
import akka.actor.ActorSystem

object SprayTest extends App with SimpleRoutingApp {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-system")

  startServer(interface = "localhost", port = 8080) {
    path("hello") {
      get {
        complete {
          <h1>Say hello to spray</h1>
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I receive the following compile errors:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - not found: value port
    - bad symbolic reference to spray.can encountered in class file 'SimpleRoutingApp.class'. Cannot 
     access term can in package spray. The current classpath may be missing a definition for spray.can, or 
     SimpleRoutingApp.class may have been compiled against a version that's incompatible with the one 
     found on the current classpath.
    - not found: value interface
```

Does anyone know what might be the issue? BTW, I'm very new to spray and actors, so I lack a lot of intuition for how spray and actors work (that's why I'm doing this simple tutorial).

Comment: You have to explicitly add XML literals to scalable 2.11. Did you do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found the answer myself. I needed to add the spray-can dependency to my pom file. Leaving this question and answer in case anyone else runs into the same problem.

SBT example:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

val akkaVersion = "2.3.6"

val sprayVersion = "1.3.2"

resolvers ++= Seq(
    "Spray Repository" at "http://repo.spray.io/"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaVersion,
    "io.spray" %% "spray-can" % sprayVersion,
    "io.spray" %% "spray-routing" % sprayVersion
)
```